# Check if current URL contains hash

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Using Javascript how do you check if current URL contains an hash?

In test page I want to add a Javascript code to print:

```
<p>yes, there is a hash here</p>
```

if hash is present (current page http://www.example.com/test/#abc) or:

```
<p>no, there is no hash here</p>
```

if hash is not present (current page http://www.example.com/test/).

Answer (score 1):

It's straightforward

```
if(window.location.hash) {
   //# in URL
}
```

Comment: We don't need **yet another** answer to this question.